# Indirectly lit objects in Cycles lose color

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting

I am struggling to resolve why objects that are lit indirectly are losing color. I am sharing two images as example of this. You can notice the difference in the barrel and underside of the tank, but also in the paneling. The paneling is supposed to be two tone, with some parts light and others dark. Yet in indirect lighting, the panels all appear to be almost the same color. And feedback would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]